# iMessage Profile Picture

Tags: macbook-pro

So recently I took a  picture for my iMessage profile using the camera, I ended up really liking the picture so I was thinking if theres any way I can save it or find it

Comment: Using the build in camera? what app did you use to take the pic?

Answer (score 1):

In iMessage - Double click the current pic to reveal the change panel.

It should open on Recents, showing you the current choice and any other pic that has been used in System Preferences > User and Groups > you account > Picture, and the Contacts App > My Card > your pic.

or

Messages Menu > Change my Picture!